# What is inserting an inline style attribute into my code?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, inline-styles

Here's a sample of the code my view is generating:

```
<button class="keyboard-button bg-success" type="button">t</button>
```

Here's what it looks like in the inspector (both Firefox and Chrome):

```
<button class="keyboard-button bg-success" type="button" style="background-color: white;">t</button>
```

The problem is that the inline style attribute takes precedence over the `bg` class, so it's overriding my desired styling.

When I search for `style=` in my app code I have no hits.

Is it possible something is happening in the way I've configured the app? Here's the package.json:

```
{
  "name": "arthur",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@rails/actioncable": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/activestorage": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/ujs": "^6.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "3.4.1",
    "jquery": "3.4.1",
    "turbolinks": "^5.2.0",
    "webpack": "^4.46.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12"
  },
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object": "^7.21.11",
    "@rails/webpacker": "^5.4.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can add a "breakpoint" on attribute changes in the chrome inspector.
make sure your JS stops very early, e.g. by adding

```
<script>debugger;</script>
```

at the bottom of your `<body>`, and then add a breakpoint to attribute modifications:
[image]

let it continue and wait for the breakpoint to be hit

Comment: Thank you. Found it right away, and it was my bad. The debugger stopped at `… elem.style.backgroundColor = 'white'` !